# SQlite REPLACE issue

Tags: sqlite, replace

I have a date in the format 'MM/DD/YYYY'.  I need the month, day, and year to be separated by : or - for functions like strftime to work in sqlite.  I'm attempting to use REPLACE but it won't work on '/'.

Any help is appreciated.

```
UPDATE table SET date = REPLACE(date,'/','-')
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you replace `/` with `-`, the date functions of SQLite will not work with your dates.
The only valid date format for SQLite is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Update the column `date` to that format like this:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET date = SUBSTR(date, -4) || '-' || SUBSTR(date, 1, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR(date, 4, 2);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=39a7b029908de1bca912b1d94819376f).

Comment: Thanks, though this doesn't account for dates like 1/1/2020.  I need a way to add a leading 0 if the number string is less than 10.

Comment: @HelpWithR a date like "1/1/2020" is not in the MM/DD/YYYY format which you mention in your question.

Comment: Yes, I need a way to account for the various ways this date can appear since they don't have leading zeros.  So, M/D/YYYY, MM/D/YYYY, M/DD/YYYY so that  the function you provided will work.

Comment: @HelpWithR The code I provided works for the requirement of the question as you posted it. If you have a new requirement you can post a new question.